# asp identity - add new user with existing username

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

asp identity - add new user with existing username.

I want to add a new user, but how can I add that with an existing username. My purpose would be to duplicate the username. But identity does not allow that.

Comment: How should ASP Identity decide which password is the correct one if the given username is not unique?

Comment: The user will sign in using email. Just email is unique.

Comment: I see. So when you talk about the "username", you do not refer to the name used for login, but to some additional name that is used for display purposes only. Maybe this tutorial can help you store these additional data: [ASP.NET Identity: How to store additional user's data in claims](https://korzh.com/blogs/net-tricks/aspnet-identity-store-user-data-in-claims)

Comment: Why not use email as a username then?